# Delete Jquery-ui sortable list item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Simple question about Jquery-UI sortable lists (http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#default)

I have made:

```
<ul id="sortable">
<li class="ui-state-default">An item 
<input class="delit" type="submit" value="Delete" />
</li>
</ul>
```

How can I make each item have a button that deletes the item it is next to?  What's the syntax for this?

Comment: Do you want to delete the next li item ?

Comment: not the next, I want to delete the li item that the delete button is inside...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">An item 
        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$("#sortable .delete").click(function() { 
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```